# ssl certificate subject name does not match target name when trying to install heroku on ubuntu 16:04

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I am trying to install heroku cli on ubuntu 16:04

When follow the installation steps and enter 3rd command `$ sudo apt-get update` it spits out following error

```
SSL: certificate subject name (*.herokuapp.com) does not match target host name 'cli-assests.heroku.com'
The repository does not have a Release file.
```

and then said some index files failed to download.

I don't understand how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising, but I think you had the *exact* same typo that I had! 
The URL, of course, is `cli-assets.heroku.com`, not `cli-assests.heroku.com`.

To fix it, you just need to edit (as root) the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Near the bottom you should see the above URL. Remove that pesky extra `s` in `assests`, then re-run the command `sudo apt-get update`.